# Cron Expression to schedule every 360 days

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, cron-task

I need to schedule a process to run every 360th day of the year. According to [this](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html) there is a field to add year related options. But I am unable to figure out how to schedule it with 360 days duration.

Can someone help to find how to write the cron job to schedule a process to run every 360th day?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

for every 360 days following expression will work

```
 0 0 12 1/360 * ? *
```

for more details please refer http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: Cron format 0 0 12 1/360 * ? *
Start time Saturday, May 27, 2017 2:09 AM Change
Next scheduled dates 

1. Thursday, June 1, 2017 12:00 PM
2. Saturday, July 1, 2017 12:00 PM
3. Tuesday, August 1, 2017 12:00 PM
4. Friday, September 1, 2017 12:00 PM
5. Sunday, October 1, 2017 12:00 PM